# What is the OSX Chrome DevTools shortcut to "list available values for a property"?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know what the Mac shortcut combination is to make Chrome Dev Tools show the list of supported values for a CSS property?

The Google documentation shows a Windows shortcut (ctrl+space) but no Mac counterpart...
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#css-autocomplete

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Also, since about Chrome 30, the property value suggestions will pop up automatically for a new CSS property.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I realized after some frustration that  Ctrl+Space doesn't apply when editing in the "sources" tab, only in "elements". Oh well!